# Working around addition not being a method in int (and other primitives)

Tags: c#, reflection

I am creating essentially a tool for visual coding and one of the elements you can put in is a function node. You select from a list a function this node will be representing. If the method is generic, you then select from a list of types what concrete type you want to use.

I am attempting to add a layer on to generic constraints to allow me to only have types with certain static methods (not possible with the current constraint system) specifically to allow requiring that a type has operators overloaded so you can have say an addition method.

The way I do this is through an attribute like this:

```
[StaticConstraint(StaticConstraint.StaticConstraintType.eConstraint_Plus)]
public static T Sum<T>(T A, T B)
```

Which is saying the parameters need to have `operator+` implemented. Then, when I am filtering my list of types I am doing this:

```
StaticConstraint[] lSConstraints = lMethod.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(StaticConstraint), false) as StaticConstraint[];

foreach (Type lType in PropertiesWindow.Project.ProjectTypes)
{
    bool lSatisfiedAllStatic = true;
    foreach (StaticConstraint lConstraint in lSConstraints)
    {
        if (!lConstraint.MatchesConstraint(lType))
        {
            lSatisfiedAllStatic = false;
        }
    }


    if (lSatisfiedAllStatic)
    {
        lSuitableTypes.Add(lType);
    }
}
```

Which calls the following matches constraint method:

```
private bool DoesTypeHaveMethodMatch(Type lType)
{

    MethodInfo lMethod = lType.GetMethod(MethodName);

    if (lMethod == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (!lMethod.ReturnType.Equals(ReturnType))
    {
        return false;
    }

    ParameterInfo[] lParams = lMethod.GetParameters();

    IEnumerable<Type> lParamTypes = lParams.Select<ParameterInfo, Type>((lParam) => { return lParam.ParameterType; });

    if (!lParamTypes.DoMatch(Parameters))
    {
        return false;
    }

    return lMethod;
}
```

Which is a method on a `MethodDescription` which I define for each constraint type (like `eConstraint_Plus`). For plus, this is as follows for a given `lType`:

```
MethodDescription lPlusOp = new MethodDescription();
lPlusOp.MethodName = "op_Addition";
lPlusOp.Parameters.AddRange(new Type[]{lType, lType});
lPlusOp.ReturnType = lType;
```

This works great with user types that do operator overloading. Of course, what I now discover is that primitives like `int` don't have the magical op_Addition method and I will have to handle these types manually. Which is unfortunate, but my problem really starts when I add my second feature:

```
[StaticConstraint(StaticConstraint.StaticConstraintType.eConstraint_Plus)]
public static T Sum<T>(T A, T B)
{
    MethodInfo lPlusMethod = StaticConstraint.GetOperation(StaticConstraint.StaticConstraintType.eConstraint_Plus, typeof(T));

    return (T)lPlusMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { A, B });
}
```

In a function where you have provided a static constraint as above, I want to be able to get the `MethodInfo` "safely" and just invoke the operation how you would like without having people providing these methods having to faff around with reflection.

However, there is no method for me to hardcode return in the event of a primitive type. I don't really want to write a addition, subtraction, multiplication (etc.) method for each primitive type.

**TL;DR: Need to return something that I can invoke with an unspecified number of parameters but where sometimes is some code that doesn't have a method to point to**

Thanks in advance and sorry for the length.

Comment: Consider using 'dynamic' when actually running the addition and letting the (runtime) compiler worry about the corner cases.

Comment: Many Internet bits have been expended on operator+() not being generic.  Quite disproportional to the number of T's that actually have the operator.  A bounded set counted with just one or two hands, supported by method overloads.

Comment: The miscutil library provides classes for using operators generically (using Linq.Expressions). http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/

Comment: @William this was a great help thanks, I used this as the simple way to call the operator after using my system to guarantee the operator was there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This occurred to me almost immediately after posting this, but I am eager to hear of a better way.

We can return a `Func<object, object[]>` instead of a MethodInfo.

This function then either invokes the relevant MethodInfo or in the edge cases can create such a `Func` and cast the parameters to whatever type is required.

**Update**: As suggested I used [MiscUtil](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/) inside the method to call the operator. Combined with my check (with a hard coded list of types), this allows easy checking that a type implements the operator and easy calling of said operator.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using Expression trees.

You might generate an expression inside your constraint's implementation (using whatever types supplied) and then attempt to compile it. May be too expensive computationally (depending on when it fails for incompatible arguments), but it really "depends".

See more details on Expressions here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression_methods(v=vs.110).aspx

**UPDATE:** By the way, if it is just about predefined primitives, why don't you simply handle them explicitly? .NET does not have that many predefined value types.

Comment: I ended up using Skeet's MiscUtil library but I believe this uses expression trees so thanks :)